# iOS - exception when checking if string is empty

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am doing something like this:

```
// GET THE USER ID
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *user_id = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

And then checking whether the user_id is empty

```
if ([user_id length] == 0) {
  proceed = false;
  NSLog(@"Error: User id is not set.");
}
```

And I get this runtime exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1469f70'

Any idea why I get the exception? I didn't think there was anything too wrong with what I was doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
NSString *user_id = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

Is returning an `NSNumber` (as `NSCFBoolean` is a private subclass of `NSNumber`) rather than a string. It therefore doesn't implement `length`, causing the exception.

Perhaps you want to test `[user_id intValue] > 0`? Even if you convert it to a string it'll always have some length.

(side issues raised: merely declaring `user_id` as a reference to an `NSString` doesn't mean that anything you assign to it magically becomes a string; indeed there are no type object-type coercion effects whatsoever. The compiler doesn't complain because the `NSUserDefaults` return objects of type `id`, i.e. it guarantees they're objects but makes no claims as to their type, and the compiler doesn't know either. All objects may be cast to and from `id` without generating a warning, so that it can be used by classes such as the user defaults, `NSArray`, etc, where they can accept anything as long as it's an object).

EDIT: based on issues raised in the comments, it sounds like the thing originally being stored may not be a string. A good way to validate web stuff is probably something like:

```
// fall through here if the object isn't a string
if(![responseString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    // check whether it's something that can be converted to a string
    if(![responseString respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)])
    {
        // some sort of error condition; the server returned something
        // that isn't a string and doesn't convert (in and of itself) to string
    }
    else
    {
        // convert the object to a string
        responseString = [responseString stringValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I wanted to get the actual user_id value which is a string value I am putting in there.  What would have been the correct way to get that string from standardUserDefaults?  Thanks!

Comment: how can we be so sure that `user_id` is not of NSString type? it could be an alphanumeric or numeric string.

Comment: @GeekedOut If the user defaults is storing a number, you must have stored a number. It doesn't change the type. Just to confirm: `user_id` is genuinely a local variable — that's not merely a quick edit you made for posting the question is it? Try adding `NSLog(@"%@", [user_id class])` or `if([user_id isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) NSLog(@"is number")` to convince yourself.  @samfisher the exception raised indicates the type of the object that `length` is sent to is `NSCFBoolean`, and that's a private subclass of `NSNumber` (the latter being a cluster in practice).

Comment: @Tommy hmmm, well I set the user_id in another controller like this: NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

                 [standardUserDefaults setObject:responseString forKey:@"user_id"];

Comment: @Tommy if the string that contained the responseString s actually a number, did the system convert it for me to be a number? I am confused how I set it as a string, but now its an integer :)

Comment: @GeekedOut it shouldn't be adjusting type for you — apart from the obvious question about whether you're sure `responseString` is definitely a string (eg, if it's come in from a web service or somewhere like that, did you test its type at the time?), if `user_id` really is local then I'm confused. If it were an instance variable that you're actually looking at again later then the correct answer might be lifecycle related.

Comment: @Tommy I think responseString is a string because I am returning it from my web service.  What would be a good way to check that variable to make sure it is indeed a string?

Comment: @GeekedOut a Boolean test would be `[responseString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`. I'll add a quick construct to my answer to explain in more detail...

Comment: @Tommy I also get a warnign about incompatible types when I do this: BOOL *proceed = TRUE; ...maybe it is related?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14473/discussion-between-tommy-and-geekedout)

Comment: Trying the suggestion in your edit now...looks like you are right - that variable isn't a string in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error is you are trying to call 'length' on what appears to be a boolean.  Either way, for checking if a string is blank here are some easy methods you can add to the NSString class by means of a category:

```
    -(BOOL)isBlank{
        return [[self trim] length]==0;
    }
    -(NSString *)trim{
        return [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] ];
    }
```

Then to call it it's just:

```
    [myString isBlank];
```